# How can I use wp_query to show all product data using just the products ID?

Tags: php, posts, wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

While on a product page (product 1), I am trying to pull through information about a different relevant product (product 2).

To create a kind of 'you may also like' list of products.

I am trying the simplest of WP_Query but cannot figure out how to pull through all the product data from one product (product 2) in a list so I can see ahead of time what will be available to bring across to the product I am currently browsing (product 1).

I need something along the lines of this:

```
<?php
$additional_forms_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'p' => $other_form_product_id
);

$additional_form_query = new WP_Query($additional_forms_args);

if ( $additional_form_query->have_posts() ) :

    while ( $additional_form_query->have_posts() ) : $additional_form_query->the_post();

            global $product;

            $attributes = $product->get_attributes();

            var_dump( $attributes );

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

endif;
```

I am expecting a var_dump of the products data I have inserted the product_id of.

I expect to see an array of product data for the product with the ID of what I place into the args, instead I get an empty array:

array(0) { }

**Please can someone help me to gather all product data associated with a product separate to the one I am currently browsing and dump its data for inspection?**

**EDIT** (refine question):

I also have this snippet creating a variable on my products:

```
woocommerce_wp_checkbox(
    array(
        'id' => 'greener_production',
        'wrapper_class' => 'show_if_simple',
        'label' => __('Greener Production', 'woocommerce'),
        'description' => __('Tick if this product is the result of Greener Production', 'woocommerce'),
    )
);
```

Within this same snippet could we query this to see if this is ticked or not 'yes : no'?

Thanks, Jason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I literally did this same thing this morning. Here's a function that you can use. You can add the function to your functions.php (or wherever) and then call the function on your template:

```
 /**
 * @param array $product_ids product_id the product id for the product you want to retrieve.
 *
 * @return string the HTML output
 */
function wpse361339_relevant_products( $product_ids = [] ) {
    global $post;

    // Bail early if there is not product ids.
    if ( is_empty( $product_ids ) ) :
         return;
    endif;

    // Args here
    $args = [
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'post__in'       => $product_ids,
        // MORE ARGS HERE IF NECESSARY
    ];

    $related_products = get_posts( $args );

    $product_output = '';

    foreach ( $related_products as $related_product ) {

        // Get the product object so we have access to the attributes.
        $product = wc_get_product( $related_product->ID );

        // $product_output .= BUILD YOUR MARKUP HERE
        echo '<pre>' . print_r( $product, TRUE ) . '</pre>';

    }

    return $product_output;
}
```

I made it so you can pass whatever product ids you want as an array to the function. Then do what you want with the attributes.

To use on your template:
`wpse361339_relevant_products( [ 'product_id_here' ] );`

**EDIT**
To get the attributes in the `WP_Query()`, you can simply do this inside of your `while` loop:

```
$product_data = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
var_dump( $product_data );
```

In context:

```
<?php
$additional_forms_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'p' => $other_form_product_id
);

$additional_form_query = new WP_Query($additional_forms_args);

if ( $additional_form_query->have_posts() ) :

    while ( $additional_form_query->have_posts() ) : $additional_form_query->the_post();

            $product_data = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
            var_dump( $product_data );

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

endif;
```

To get specific *product data* you can use the methods from: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html

Like `$product_data->get_title()` will get you the title.

**EDIT 2**
The checkbox data is saved in the product meta, so you get it:
`$product_data->get_meta();`

Comment: Thanks for contributing, are you able to follow the method I have started closer? I don't want it to be a separate function I am calling I am more interested at this stage how it is possible to access a products full attribute list using a WP_Query. I am open to using a query to WC too. Many thanks, J.

Comment: I sure can! Give me a bit and I'll post more in line with what you have. I personally like the function method because it's transportable throughout your code.

Comment: I fully appreciate that, it is a very tidy way to build up a set of functions that can be used all over. Don't delete this answer, just expand into another means of achieving the same result. p.s. you open an if with a '{' and close with 'endif;'. I think that may cause an issue.

Comment: Whoops! I normally don't use the `{}` hah! Good catch. I fixed the typo, also added the variables/methods to put into your loop (which I'm sure you saw)

Comment: Neither do I.. I wonder why that is :S I will try the snippet now!

Comment: I get a blank array returned, just double checked the product ID I am using too. That part matches up...

Comment: This may seem silly, but do you have attributes assigned on that product? In my tests, I run a loop and for the products that do not have attributes, I get a blank arrays.

Comment: I tested the exact code, using your `WP_Query` method as I provided and it worked as expected.

Comment: I am running this code within a different products loop / description, does that shed some light?

Comment: That's exactly how I'm doing it. I have my main product detail page, then I put your `WP_Query` version just below the content (still in the main loop). I'm looping 4 other products - I get the attributes for the product I know has attributes. The other three do not. So, I get blank arrays for the the three, but the data I expect for the one that does.

Comment: attributes being, title, description, custom attributes?

Comment: Product attributes - like size, weight, any custom attributes added to the Attributes tab on the product edit screen.

Comment: Yo this is where I am going wrong then, how can I see a list of all the attributes such as the title, description, categories, tags, I have also added a custom attribute in the general product data, can I list these out too?

Comment: I can appreciate these probably have a different terminology to attribute..

Comment: Yeah, attribute is very specific in WC to mean product attributes.

Comment: Bah! I am daft like... So you think I could rephrase my question slightly and gather the correct.. 'pieces' that I require?

Comment: I updated my answer for you. `wp_product_data` has all that information. Here's all the functions that get you what you want. https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html

Comment: Yeah, you should just update it to you want "product data"

Comment: I have just expanded my question a little, its in the edit. Is that possible?

Comment: Yeah, updated answer. Use `->get_meta()` I think if you have further questions for this, we should probably open up a new question :)

Comment: You're spot on once again! Massive help, appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use de `WP_Query` object.
The `get_posts()` function will make it in a much better way. And you can use     all the `$args` that applies to conventional WP posts.

Note the include argument, which includes in the query only the products with given ID.

```
 $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 
            'orderby' => 'date', 'order'=>'DESC', 
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'include'=> array(
                'ID' => /*product ID here (int)*/
            ) 
        );
        $product = get_posts( $args );
```